# Is the older behaviour (easier to break out of search term entry) of / searches still available?

Tags: search, cursor-movement

I remember older vim installations (in 2.4.x/2.6.x era linux distributions) behaving differently with / searches, often you were able to almost instantly follow the search up with an edit or movement command centered on the instance found, without explicitly breaking out of entering the search term with ENTER. Not sure if it was a timeout on search term entry, or cursor keys etc working like ENTER.

How are modern vim installations configured differently, and can the original behaviour be reinstated?

Comment: Let’s say i type `/a`; how would you expect Vim to decide the next `j` should be “accept search and go down a line” instead of “add j to the search query”?

Comment: For whatever reason, at least it seems some installations clearly knew  the keyboard cursor keys don't belong in the search term :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you used a bug/shortcoming as a feature! The cursor keys work by sending the escape character (which is also what the Escape key sends) followed by a code indicating which arrow key you pressed (which code depends on the system, but it's `[D` for me on left arrow key), and sounds like Vim misinterpreted that as if you had pressed Escape, either due to a problem in Vim or due to a problem in your setup (e.g. wrong TERM value).

You can still get this behaviour back by mapping the arrow keys to escape:

```
cnoremap <Left>  <Esc>
cnoremap <Right> <Esc>
cnoremap <Up>    <Esc>
cnoremap <Down>  <Esc>
```

You can also use `<CR>` in place of `<Esc>` for the enter key.

This will work on *any* commandline, including with `:`. If you only want it to work for search you'll need a slightly more complex expression mapping:

```
cnoremap <expr> <Left>  '/?'->stridx(getcmdtype()) == -1 ? '<Left>'  : '<Esc>'
cnoremap <expr> <Right> '/?'->stridx(getcmdtype()) == -1 ? '<Right>' : '<Esc>' 
cnoremap <expr> <Up>    '/?'->stridx(getcmdtype()) == -1 ? '<Up>'    : '<Esc>' 
cnoremap <expr> <Down>  '/?'->stridx(getcmdtype()) == -1 ? '<Down>'  : '<Esc>'
```

This will send `<Esc>` if `getcmdtype()` is `/` or `?`, or the original arrow key otherwise.

Comment: You can probably also set a timeout on the `/` commandline if you want with `timer_start()` that resets on every keypress, but that's a bit more work.

Comment: Explicitly mapping in an ESC would also leave insert mode? Not the intended side effect :(

Comment: I don't know what you mean @rackandboneman; you're not in insert mode when searching?

Comment: Yes, but would remapping the cursor keys not make them unusable in insert mode?

Comment: @rackandboneman No, cnoremap only maps keys in the commandline. That's why we check if the commandline type is `/` or `?`, so it *doesn't* work for `:`.